# TToolButton Height Grows with Style = tbsDropdown

Tags: delphi

I noticed that the height of a TToolButton increases when you set the button's Style to tbsDropdown. I can understand the width increasing, so the button has space to draw the down arrow, but I'm not sure a height increase is necessary.

Steps to reproduce the issue (Delphi 2010, Windows 7 x64):

- Add TToolbar to a form, ShowCaptions=True
- Right click to add a button to the Toolbar
- Set button Style=tbsDropDown and notice the button grows in height

The same height increase happens when there are images assigned to the
toolbar, in which case there is already plenty more vertical space available
in the button to draw the drop down.

Here's a visual example:
[alt text http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1462/ttoolbar02.png](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1462/ttoolbar02.png)
[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/966/ttoolbar01.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/966/ttoolbar01.png)

Is there a workaround for this without hacking the VCL, or is this hardcoded into the Windows control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the underlying Windows control. A quick look into `ComCtrls` shows that changing the `TToolButton.Style` calls it's `SetStyle` method. If, in `SetStyle`, `ShowCaptions` is True then the `TToolBar.ButtonWidth` and `ButtonHeight` are both set to 0, and `TToolButton.RecreateButtons` is called.

`RecreateButtons`, in turn, calls `TToolBar.ResizeButtons`, which simply sends (posts) a message to the `ToolBar` using

```
Perform(TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
```

`TB_AUTOSIZE` is intended to be used, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787295(VS.85).aspx),

> after causing the size of a toolbar to change either by setting the button or bitmap size or by adding strings for the first time.

Since `SetStyle` sets both the `ButtonWidth` and `ButtonHeight` to 0, this message would seem to be correctly sent.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something is wrong with the theme support in underlying windows control. Switch off the runtime themes (Project/Options/Application, uncheck "Enable runtime themes" checkbox), ignore the increased button heights at design time (Delphi IDE uses themes) and run the application - you will see normal heights of the toolbar buttons.